# Trying to get an error message to appear based on invalid form input

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm working on a web app that lets you enter a bill amount and a tip amount (as a percentage). The amounts are entered into text fields, and the results are rendered in spans next to them. It converts the percentage to a dollar amount and displays it, and it calculates the total bill by multiplying the bill amount with the tip amount. It does this dynamically, so that you don't have to press any buttons.

The snag that I ran into is error handling. I have an error message in a hidden div, and I unhide it when the input in any of the fields is invalid.

There are two problems with my code, though:

The first field (bill) displays the error message even if the user has deleted everything. I want the error message to disappear if the field is empty.

The second field (tip) doesn't display the error message at all, even though it uses almost exactly the same code.

I know there's a lot of redundancy and I need to refactor my code, but I'm just trying to get it to work right now.

```js
function createTipCalculator(spec) {
  let {bill, tip} = spec,
    setBill = function(num) {
      bill = num;
    },
    setTip = function(num) {
      tip = num;
    },
    getBill = function() {
      return parseFloat(bill);
    },
    getTip = function() {
      return Number(tip);
    },
    roundToCents = function(num) {
      return Math.round((num + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
    },
    tipDecimal = function() {
      const tipDec = roundToCents(getBill() * (getTip()/100));
      return tipDec;
    },
    valToCurrency = function(value) {
      return value.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', minimumFractionDigits: 2});
    },
    total = function() {
      const tipToDec = tipDecimal();
      return valToCurrency(getBill() + tipToDec);
    },
    attachNodeVal = function(element, value) {
      const valCurrency = valToCurrency(value);
      const newText = document.createTextNode(valCurrency);  
    
      // If text node is already there, delete it
      if (element.textContent){
        element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
      }
      element.appendChild(newText);
      return element;
    },
    calculate = function(tipOutput, totalOutput) {
      const tipTotal = tipDecimal();
      const billTotal = total();
      
      attachNodeVal(tipOutput, tipTotal);
      attachNodeVal(totalOutput, billTotal);
    },
    isValid = function(value) {
      // Convert string into number. If it's a non-numeric string,
      // it'll return 0
      return Number(value) ? true : false;
    },
    warningMessage = function(element, 
      message = "Error! Please enter a numeric value") {
        attachNodeVal(element, message);
        return element;
    }

  return Object.freeze({
      setBill, 
      setTip,
      getBill,
      getTip,
      roundToCents,
      tipDecimal,
      total,
      attachNodeVal,
      calculate,
      isValid,
      warningMessage
    });
}

(function(){
  "use strict";
  const bill = document.querySelector("#bill"),
        tip = document.querySelector("#tip"),
        tipAmountOutput = document.querySelector("#tip-amount"),
        totalOutput = document.querySelector("#total"),
        error = document.querySelector("#error");
  let billAmt = bill.value;
  let tipAmt = tip.value || tip.placeholder;
  const tipCalculator = 
    createTipCalculator({bill: billAmt, tip: tipAmt});

  bill.addEventListener("input", 
    function() {
      error.classList.add("hidden");
      billAmt = bill.value;
      tipCalculator.setBill(billAmt);
      tipCalculator.calculate(tipAmountOutput, totalOutput);
      if (!tipCalculator.isValid(billAmt)) {
        error.classList.remove("hidden");
      } else {
        error.classList.add("hidden");
      }
  });
  tip.addEventListener("input", 
   function() {
    error.classList.add("hidden");
    tipAmt = tip.value || tip.placeholder;
    tipCalculator.setTip(tipAmt);
    tipCalculator.calculate(tipAmountOutput, totalOutput);
    if (!tipCalculator.isValid(tipAmt)) {
      error.classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
      error.classList.add("hidden");
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
.hidden {
 visibility: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
  <title>Tip Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form-calc">
    <label for="bill">Bill Amount: </label><input id="bill" class="form-input" name="bill" type="number" min="0" placeholder="0" step="any" required />
    <label for="tip">Tip: </label><input type="number" id="tip" class="form-input" placeholder="15" />
    <span>Tip Amount: </span>
    <span id="tip-amount"></span>
    <span>Total: </span>
    <span id="total"></span>
  </form>
  <div id="error" class="hidden"><span id="error-message">Error! Please enter a numeric value!</span></div>
  <script type="module" src="./js/tip.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make this a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and add the HTML so we can test it?

Comment: What should happen if the tip is invalid but you empty the bill input, or vice versa? Using the same error field for both makes this complicated.

Comment: Okay, I updated it with all of the code.

Comment: I get an error message when I enter an empty value in `Tip`